# Android Speech recognizer length

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to know if there's a limit how long the speech recognizer can listen.  Either due to an actual time limit to how long speech recognizer listens or due to the fact that what the user said is too long for Google to process properly and will reply ERROR_NO_MATCH (constant value of 7).

Also, if there is a limit, I would like to know if different languages has different limits.